# Help with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will recognize # followed by a number in a string and make it clickable. Only if its # and a number like ex: #758 and make i clickable. Not # 758. Youtube has this for example.

Would really appreciate if someone could give me some hints since im worthless on regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/#\\d+/', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $str);
```

The regex is basically `/#\d+/`, so the `#` character followed by one or more digits. `preg_replace` is to replace such occurences with `<a href="$0">$0</a>` where `$0` is replaced by the match that has been found.

And if you just need the number, use `/#(\d+)/` and `<a href="$1">$1</a>` instead.

Comment: @Gumbo: does $0 contain the whole match?

Comment: @Renesis: Yes, `$0` contains the whole match.